# PHP: Ask for a safe way to read data from $_POST and write to file

Tags: php, security, output, user-input

I am asking a safe way to read data from $_POST and write to file in PHP, because our PHP code was pointed out to be insecure. The criticism stated that our way may lead to opportunity for attackers to "**destroy the data files, or create unexpected new files**".

Please consider the following PHP code:

```
function read_POST($key)
{
    $value = 'NULL';
    // Check whether the $_POST[$key] is set.
    if (array_key_exists($key, $_POST) !== true)
        return $value;
    // Restrict the length of user input.
    $value = substr($_POST[$key], 0, 128);
    // Remove possible scripting.
    $value = trim(preg_replace("/<\?.*\?>/", '', $value));
    // Convert all HTML special characters properly.
    $value = filter_var($value, FILTER_SANITIZE_FULL_SPECIAL_CHARS);
    return $value;
}

$val1 = read_POST('user_inp1');
$val2 = read_POST('user_inp2');
$val3 = read_POST('user_inp3');
if (($f = fopen('/some/path/of/data/file', 'w')) == True) {
    fwrite($f, "Name: $val1\n");
    fwrite($f, "Location: $val2\n");
    fwrite($f, "Weather: $val3\n");
    fclose($f);
}
```

Here, for simplicity, assuming that all the read values can be arbitrary (but safely sanitized) strings. Are there any security issues with this piece of code? If yes, how to improve it?

Comment: Probably better to ask this on [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Well, given the code in your question, it would be very easy to overwrite whatever was there, however I don't see how new files can be created. I think we're not getting all of the code here.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware `it would be very easy to overwrite whatever was there`. How? `fwrite` appends data at the end of the file.

Comment: @Paolo Yes, you're right, but `fopen` is using `'w'` and that means: _"Open for writing only; place the file pointer at the beginning of the file and truncate the file to zero length. If the file does not exist, attempt to create it."_

Comment: @KIKOSoftware, yes your're right

Answer (score 0):

There are no way for an attacker to destory or create files arbitrarily as you're just writing to one specific file and the file name is hard coded.

Here some insights:

---

```php
// Restrict the length of user input.
$value = substr($_POST[$key], 0, 128);
```

I assume you want to support unicode text, after all we are in 2022 at the time of writing. The easieast way is set up everithing (starting from the web pages you're serving, with the forms that send your server user's data) to encode text as UTF-8. If you're unfamiliar with this topic you'll find plenty of resources online.

Said that it's safer to trim text in a UTF-8 aware way:

`$value = mb_substr( $value, 0, 128 );`

Note that this way you may end with a string that takes more than 128 bytes of size (since utf-8 encoded characters may take up to 4 bytes).

---

```php
// Remove possible scripting.
$value = trim(preg_replace("/<\?.*\?>/", '', $value));
// Convert all HTML special characters properly.
$value = filter_var($value, FILTER_SANITIZE_FULL_SPECIAL_CHARS);
```

I would not do this here. You're storing text.
When you will need that text then you'll escape it depending on where you will use it. Is it a web page? Then html-encode. Is it a url fragment? url-encode it. Is it a db? If the db is configured to receive UTF-8 text then nothing to do.

The only thing you need to do is avoid newlines `\n` due to the way you're saving data.
If you do the sanitization as per your code then newlines are already stripped away.
If you follow my advice then you'll need to do it.

```php
$value = str_replace( "\n", " ", $value ); // let's turn them into spaces
$value = str_replace( "\r", " ", $value ); // let's do it for carriage returns too
```

You want to do this because a "forged" POST request where, for example, `user_inp3` is `sunny\nName: foo\nLocation: nowhere\nWeather: rainy` would result in unwanted extra record being created on the output file.

---

```php
if (($f = fopen('/some/path/of/data/file', 'w')) == True) {
    fwrite($f, "Name: $val1\n");
    fwrite($f, "Location: $val2\n");
    fwrite($f, "Weather: $val3\n");
    fclose($f);
}
```

Here you have two issues:

first as mentioned in the comments using `w` option with `fopen` will result in the file being rewritten at each script execution.
Assuming you need to keep the data use `a` and the new data will be appended to the file.

Second, you may have a concurrency issue: if two requests occurr at the same time you may have two instances of the php interpreter writing the output file at the same time messing up data.

This is why normally databases are used to store data.

If you need to stick with the filesystem approach then **lock** the file before writing, ensure the lock succeeded then unlock it at the end. See **[flock](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.flock.php)**